# using Google Contacts Api Import Contacts C#

Tags: c#, api, google-contacts-api

I am using [Google Contacts Api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/). I am not sure whether I can send an `Auth Token` as a parameter.

```
string _token = _google.Token;
RequestSettings requestSettings = new RequestSettings("AppName",_token);
ContactsRequest contactsRequest = new ContactsRequest(requestSettings);

// Get the feed
Feed<Contact> feed = contactsRequest.GetContacts();
```

I get `401 Unauthorised` as a response for this code, but if I send the username and password as parameters, I am able to get a response.

Answer (score 4):

Whoops, sorry, I didn't quite get it right the first time. I'm using this code in a real app, I just do things a bit different in my code because I'm constantly refreshing tokens.
In any case, here's the proper logic:

```
        // get this information from Google's API Console after registering your app
        var parameters = new OAuth2Parameters
        {
            ClientId = @"",
            ClientSecret = @"",
            RedirectUri = @"",
            Scope = @"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/",
        };

        // generate the authorization url
        string url = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);

        // now use the url to authorize the app in the browser and get the access code
        (...)

        // get this information from Google's API Console after registering your app
        parameters.AccessCode = @"<from previous step>";

        // get an access token
        OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);

        // setup connection to contacts service
        var contacts = new ContactsRequest(new RequestSettings("<appname>", parameters));

        // get each contact
        foreach (var contact in contacts.GetContacts().Entries)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(contact.ContactEntry.Name.FullName);
        }
```

FYI, after you call `GetAccessToken()` against your access code, your parameters data structure will include the `AccessToken` and `RefreshToken` fields.  If you STORE these two values, you can set them in the parameters structure in subsequent calls (allowing you to skip asking for authorization in the future) and instead of calling `GetAccessToken()` simply call `RefreshAccessToken(parameters)` and you'll always have access to the contacts.  Make sense?  Here, take a look:

```
        // get this information from Google's API Console after registering your app
        var parameters = new OAuth2Parameters
        {
            ClientId = @"",
            ClientSecret = @"",
            RedirectUri = @"",
            Scope = @"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/",
            AccessCode = "",
            AccessToken = "",  /* use the value returned from the old call to GetAccessToken here */
            RefreshToken = "", /* use the value returned from the old call to GetAccessToken here */
        };

        // get an access token
        OAuthUtil.RefreshAccessToken(parameters);

        // setup connection to contacts service
        var contacts = new ContactsRequest(new RequestSettings("<appname>", parameters));

        // get each contact
        foreach (var contact in contacts.GetContacts().Entries)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(contact.ContactEntry.Name.FullName);
        }
```

**Edit**:

```
            // generate the authorization url
            string url = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);

            // now use the url to authorize the app in the browser and get the access code
            (...)

            // get this information from Google's API Console after registering your app
            var parameters = new OAuth2Parameters
            {
                ClientId = @"",
                ClientSecret = @"",
                RedirectUri = @"",
                Scope = @"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/",
                AccessCode = @"<from previous step>",
            };

            // get an access token
            OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);

            // setup connection to contacts service
            var contacts = new ContactsRequest(new RequestSettings("<appname>", parameters));

            // get each contact
            foreach (var contact in contacts.GetContacts().Entries)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(contact.ContactEntry.Name.FullName);
            }
```

Comment: This like every other post seems to gloss over this part: // now use the url to authorize the app in the browser and get the access code
        (...)
What does that even mean?

Comment: This sample without using OAuth2Parameters: http://dotnetoday.blogspot.com.es/2012/10/c-google-api-getting-google-contacts.html